# Randomly select element and remove other

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a slider with 5 frames and each frame has 10 layers i randomly select 2 layers by this function

```
function randomslide(slide){
    var divs = $(slide).get().sort(function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,1)
    $(divs).show();
};
```

can it is possible that the function remove other layers which is not selected to be removed from the DOM 
so it will prevent from extra loading of 8*5 = 35 layers.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
function randomslide(slide){
    var divs = $(slide).get().sort(function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;});
    $(divs).slice(2).remove();
    $(divs).show();
};
```

Comment: Doesn't it remove the layers from index 2 to the end? Or it does remove, but remove is not what you need?

Comment: i want that the page do not load the non selected slide when the page loads the html i want the function remove the layers before my webpage start fetching the images

Comment: The way the browser fetches images is usually handled by the browser loading policy. As soon as you put an image tag (or any kind of tags that load files), the browser may or may not to start loading them. Some browsers may not load the image if it's not displayed (stylesheet with `display:none`) but some may load them anyway. The only way I know to make sure it won't try to load them is to create the image tags without any URL, then sort the divs like the above code does, and then inject the URLs to the two winning divs that weren't removed.